# How to force SSL on Nginx & Varnish

Tags: nginx, php, https, varnish

how can i redirect only to https in Nginx and varnish.
I use varnish cache in port 80 and Nginx listening on 8080. Works fine in http, but i need to add SSL. my configuration is as follows

```
server {
    listen  443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen  [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name afrim.com www.afrim.com;
    port_in_redirect off;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/afrim_com_crt.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/afrim_com.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80; 
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header HTTPS "on";
    }
}

server {
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    server_name afrim.com www.afrim.com;
    root /var/www/html/;
    index index.php;
    port_in_redirect off;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }

}

server {
    listen  8080;
    listen  [::]:8080;
    server_name afrim.com www.afrim.com;
    return  301 https://afrim.com$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/redirect/ you can use the following VCL code to perform HTTP to HTTPS redirections in Varnish:

```
vcl 4.1;

import proxy;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = 8080;
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if ((req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto && req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto != "https") || 
        (req.http.Scheme && req.http.Scheme != "https")) {
        return (synth(750));
    } elseif (!req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto && !req.http.Scheme && !proxy.is_ssl()) {
        return (synth(750));
    }
}

sub vcl_synth {
    if (resp.status == 750) {
        set resp.status = 301;
        set resp.http.location = "https://" + req.http.Host + req.url;
        set resp.reason = "Moved";
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. These are my configs from an Ubuntu LEMP Digital Ocean Droplet running Nginx, Varnish and PHP-fpm. It also has the redirects to forward all traffic to https://wwww

The files are:

- default.vcl
- nginx.conf
- varnish_daemon
- varnish.service

### default.vcl

```
vcl 4.1;

import std;

backend projectname {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
    .max_connections = 100;
    .connect_timeout        = 5s;
    .first_byte_timeout     = 90s;
    .between_bytes_timeout  = 2s;
}

acl purge {
    "localhost";
    "127.0.0.1";
    "::1";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/") {
        set req.backend_hint = projectname;
        return(pipe);
    }
    

    # Forward client's IP to the backend
    if (req.restarts == 0) {
        if (req.http.X-Real-IP) {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Real-IP;
        } else if (req.http.X-Forwarded-For) {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
        } else {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
        }
    }


    set req.http.Host = regsub(req.http.Host, ":[0-9]+", "");
    unset req.http.proxy;
    set req.url = std.querysort(req.url);
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?$", "");
    set req.http.Surrogate-Capability = "key=ESI/1.0";

    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        set req.grace = 10s;
    }

    if (!req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
        if(std.port(server.ip) == 443) {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "https";
        } else {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "https";
        }
    }

    # === STATIC FILES ===
    # Properly handle different encoding types
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf)$") {
            # No point in compressing these
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elseif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elseif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            # unknown algorithm (aka crappy browser)
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

    if (req.http.Upgrade ~ "(?i)websocket") {
        return (pipe);
    }

    if (req.url ~ "(\?|&)(utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=") {
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "&(utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=([A-z0-9_\-\.%25]+)", "");
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "\?(utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=([A-z0-9_\-\.%25]+)", "?");
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?&", "?");
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?$", "");
    }

    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
            return (synth(405, client.ip + " is not allowed to send PURGE requests."));
        }
        return (purge);
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" &&
        req.method != "HEAD" &&
        req.method != "PUT" &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.method != "TRACE" &&
        req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.method != "PATCH" &&
        req.method != "DELETE") {
        return (pipe);
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }

    if (req.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(7z|avi|bmp|bz2|css|csv|doc|docx|eot|flac|flv|gif|gz|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|less|mka|mkv|mov|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|odt|ogg|ogm|opus|otf|pdf|png|ppt|pptx|rar|rtf|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tbz|tgz|ttf|txt|txz|wav|webm|webp|woff|woff2|xls|xlsx|xml|xz|zip)(\?.*)?$") {
        unset req.http.Cookie;
        return(hash);
    }

    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(__utm|_ga|_opt)[a-z_]*=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(__)?hs[a-z_\-]+=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "hubspotutk=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "_hj[a-zA-Z]+=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(NID|DSID|__gads|GED_PLAYLIST_ACTIVITY|ACLK_DATA|ANID|AID|IDE|TAID|_gcl_[a-z]*|FLC|RUL|PAIDCONTENT|1P_JAR|Conversion|VISITOR_INFO1[a-z_]*)=[^;]+(; )?", "");
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "^;\s*", "");

    if (req.http.cookie ~ "^\s*$") {
        unset req.http.cookie;
    }
}

sub vcl_pipe {
    if (req.backend_hint == projectname) {
        set req.http.Connection = "close";
        return(pipe);
    }
}

sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (bereq.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(7z|avi|bmp|bz2|css|csv|doc|docx|eot|flac|flv|gif|gz|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|less|mka|mkv|mov|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|odt|ogg|ogm|opus|otf|pdf|png|ppt|pptx|rar|rtf|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tbz|tgz|ttf|txt|txz|wav|webm|webp|woff|woff2|xls|xlsx|xml|xz|zip)(\?.*)?$") {
        unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
        set beresp.ttl = 1d;
    }

    if (beresp.http.Surrogate-Control ~ "ESI/1.0") {
        unset beresp.http.Surrogate-Control;
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }

    # Unset the "pragma" header (suggested)
    unset beresp.http.Pragma;

    # Unset the "vary" header (suggested)
    unset beresp.http.Vary;

    set beresp.ttl = 10s;
    set beresp.grace = 2h;
}
```

### nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 38000;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    autoindex off;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    keepalive_requests 100000;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    charset UTF-8;
    
    # Cloudflare IP's
    set_real_ip_from 173.245.48.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 103.22.200.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 103.31.4.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 141.101.64.0/18;
    set_real_ip_from 108.162.192.0/18;
    set_real_ip_from 190.93.240.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from 188.114.96.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from 197.234.240.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 198.41.128.0/17;
    set_real_ip_from 162.158.0.0/15;
    set_real_ip_from 104.16.0.0/12;
    set_real_ip_from 172.64.0.0/13;
    set_real_ip_from 131.0.72.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 2400:cb00::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2606:4700::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2803:f800::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2405:b500::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2405:8100::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2a06:98c0::/29;
    set_real_ip_from 2c0f:f248::/32;

    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;

    client_max_body_size 128m;

    client_body_buffer_size 2m;
    client_header_buffer_size 64k;
    large_client_header_buffers 16 128k;

    fastcgi_buffers 4 32k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 32k;

    fastcgi_connect_timeout 60s;
    fastcgi_next_upstream_timeout 40s;
    fastcgi_next_upstream_tries 10;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 60s;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 60s;
    fastcgi_cache_lock_timeout 60s;

    open_file_cache max=35000 inactive=30s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_min_length 10240;
    #gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_buffers 4 16k;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_types text/css text/js text/xml text/plain text/javascript
        text/html
        text/x-component
        application/json
        application/xml
        application/x-javascript
        application/javascript
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        application/rss+xml
        font/truetype
        font/opentype
        image/svg+xml;

    map_hash_max_size 4200;
    map_hash_bucket_size 4200;

    log_format main
        '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
        '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    map $http_user_agent $is_non_search_bot {
        default '';
        ~*(google|bing|pingdom|monitis.com|Zend_Http_Clienti) '';
        ~*(http|crawler|spider|bot|search|ForusP|Wget/|Python-urllib|PHPCrawl|bGenius) 'bot';
    }

    map $status $write_log {
        444 0;
        default 1;
    }

    map $http_user_agent $is_bad_client {
        default 0;
        ~*(Sogou) 1;
        ~*(360Spider) 1;
        ~*(aiHitBot|AhrefsBot) 1;
        ~*(betaBot|BlackWidow|Bolt|BLEXBot|BUbiNG) 1;
        ~*(CazoodleBot|CPython|CCBot|ChinaClaw|Curious|CRAZYWEBCRAWLER|Custo) 1;
        ~*(Default|DIIbot|DISCo|discobot) 1;
        ~*(Exabot|eCatch|ecxi|EirGrabber|EmailCollector|EmailSiphon|EmailWolf|ExtractorPro|EyeNetIE) 1;
        ~*(FlashGet|Findxbot) 1;
        ~*(GetRight|GetWeb!|Go!Zilla|Go-Ahead-Got-It|Go.*package.*|GrabNet|Grafula|GT::WWW|GuzzleHttp) 1;
        ~*(heritrix|HaosouSpider|HMView|HTTP::Lite|HTTrack) 1;
        ~*(ia_archiver|IDBot|id-search|id-search.org|InterGET|InternetSeer.com|IRLbot) 1;
        ~*(JetCar) 1;
        ~*(larbin|LeechFTP|Lightspeedsystems|litemage_walker|LinksManager.com_bot|Lipperhey|linkwalker|LinkpadBot|lwp-trivial|ltx71) 1;
        ~*(Maxthon$|Mail.RU_Bot|MegaIndex.ru|meanpathbot|MFC_Tear_Sample|microsoft.url|Microsoft-IIS|Mozilla.*Indy|Mozilla.*NEWT|MJ12bot|MSFrontPage) 1;
        ~*(Navroad|NearSite|NetAnts|NetLyzer.*FastProbe|NetSpider|NetZIP|Nutch) 1;
        ~*(Octopus) 1;
        ~*(PageGrabber|panscient.com|pavuk|PECL::HTTP|PeoplePal|pcBrowser|Pi-Monster|PHPCrawl|PleaseCrawl|psbot|prijsbest|python-requests) 1;
        ~*(Qwantify) 1;
        ~*(RealDownload|ReGet|RedesScrapy|Rippers|RocketCrawler) 1;
        ~*(SBIder|Scrapy|Screaming|ScreenerBot|SEOprofiler|SeaMonkey$|SeznamBot|SemrushBot|sitecheck.internetseer.com|SiteSnagger) 1;
        ~*(SmartDownload|Snoopy|SputnikBot|Steeler|SuperBot|SuperHTTP|Surfbot|sqlmap) 1;
        ~*(tAkeOut|Teleport|Toata|TwengaBot|Typhoeus) 1;
        ~*(URI::Fetch|User-Agent|UserAgent) 1;
        ~*(voltron|Vagabondo|VoidEYE|Visbot) 1;
        ~*(webalta|WebAuto|[Ww]eb[Bb]andit|WebCollage|WebCopier|WebFetch|WebLeacher|WebReaper|WebSauger|WebStripper|WebWhacker|WhatsApp) 1;
        ~*(WebZIP|Wget|Widow|Wotbox|WWW-Mechanize|WWWOFFLE) 1;
        ~*(zermelo|Zeus|Zeus.*Webster|ZyBorg) 1;
    }

    map $uri $redirected_url {
        default "none";
    }

    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=30r/s;
    limit_req_zone $is_non_search_bot zone=bots:10m rate=22r/s;

    limit_req_log_level error;

    index index.php index.html;

    upstream fastcgi_backend {
        server unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
    }

    proxy_cache_path /var/cache/varnish levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:8m max_size=1g inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;


    server {
        listen 8080;
        listen [::]:8080;
        server_name example.com;
        # redirect http to https://wwww
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }
    server {
        listen 8080;
        listen [::]:8080;
        root /var/www/current/default_site;

        server_name www.example.com;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        listen [::]:443;
        server_name example.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
        # redirect http to https://wwww
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        listen 443 ssl;
        root /var/www/current/default_site;
        server_name www.example.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
        add_header "X-XSS-Protection" "1; mode=block";

        if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php(/?)(.*)" ) {
            return 301 $1$3;
        }

        if ($is_bad_client) {
            return 444;
        }

        location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg)$ {
            access_log off;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN always;
            expires 365d;
        }
        
        location ~* \.(js|css|pdf)$ {
            expires 365d;
            access_log off;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN always;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://fast.fonts.net";
        }

        location ~* \.(html|swf)$ {
            expires 30d;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN always;
        }

        location ~* \.(eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
            access_log off;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
            add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN always;
            expires 365d;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_cache my_cache;
            proxy_cache_revalidate on;
            proxy_cache_min_uses 3;
            proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
            proxy_cache_background_update on;
            proxy_cache_lock on;

            proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires;
            proxy_ignore_headers Expires;
            proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;

            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
            # ALSO TRY YOUR SERVER IP proxy_pass http://99.100.101.102:80;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
        }
    
    }
}
```

### varnish_daemon

This is the code from "nano /etc/default/varnish"

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
    -T localhost:6082 \
    -p feature=+http2 \
    -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
    -S /etc/varnish/secret \
    -s malloc,1g"
```

### varnish.service

This is the code from "nano /lib/systemd/system/varnish.service"

```
[Unit]
Description=Varnish HTTP accelerator
Documentation=https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/6.1/ man:varnishd

[Service]
Type=simple
LimitNOFILE=131072
LimitMEMLOCK=82000
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -p feature=+http2 -s malloc,1G
ExecReload=/usr/share/varnish/varnishreload
ProtectSystem=full
ProtectHome=true
PrivateTmp=true
PrivateDevices=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).